# Missing 1 required positional arguments python

Tags: python, arguments

I'm quite new to programming, and the solution is probably easy, but if anybody could explain whats going on, it would mean heaps :)

*code*:

```
def loan (loan_amount,number_of_weeks):
    return (loan_amount/number_of_weeks)

loan_amount= int(input("Enter an amount: "))

number_of_weeks= int(input("Enter a number of weeks: "))


loan(loan_amount/number_of_weeks)

print ("you must repay",loan,"per week to repay a loan of",loan_amount,"in",number_of_weeks,"weeks")
```

*error code*:

```
Enter an amount: 5
Enter a number of weeks: 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ethan/PycharmProjects/untitled1/Loan.py", line 7, in <module>
    loan(loan_amount/number_of_weeks)
TypeError: loan() missing 1 required positional argument: 'number_of_weeks'
```

Answer (score 2):

You defined loan to take two arguments. So, you would have to call it like:

```
loan(loan_amount, number_of_weeks)
```

Heads up, you probably want to assign the result of that to a variable which you then later print. Printing `loan` prints the function object representation.

Answer (score 0):

yup, in your call to loan() you have a slash where you should have a comma.

```
loan(loan_amount/number_of_weeks)
```

should be

```
loan(loan_amount,number_of_weeks)
```

also, in the next line, you print "loan", but that's not set to anything. You can either set the output of loan to a variable:

```
loan_var = loan(loan_amount/number_of_weeks)
print ("you must repay",loan_var,"per week to repay a loan of",loan_amount,"in",number_of_weeks,"weeks")
```

or call it directly in the print statement:

```
print ("you must repay",loan(loan_amount/number_of_weeks),"per week to repay a loan of",loan_amount,"in",number_of_weeks,"weeks")
```

Comment: I added in the "loan_var" variable, bit still getting an error message.

loan(loan_amount,number_of_weeks)
loan_var = loan(loan_amount/number_of_weeks)

print ("you must repay",loan_var,"per week to repay a loan of",loan_amount,"in",number_of_weeks,"weeks")

*error*

Enter an amount: 100
Enter a number of weeks: 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ethan/PycharmProjects/untitled1/Loan.py", line 8, in <module>
    loan_var = loan(loan_amount/number_of_weeks)
TypeError: loan() missing 1 required positional argument: 'number_of_weeks'

Comment: Don't forget to replace the slash with a comma inside loan(). That's what's causing this particular error.